# Is there any software for driver maintenance?

Tags: windows, drivers, update, sccm

We use SCCM for OSD and consequently driver installation, and it works well. However, the issue becomes that when drivers are updated on the sccm server, only machines that are newly imaged and/or re-imaged get the latest drivers, and the rest don't.

Sccm does good with driver *deployment*, but not maintenance. I am looking for software or a process to deploy driver packages to machines to ensure the drivers are kept up to date.

I've seen System Center Updates Publisher, which looks promising but I am running into issues getting it up and running, still working on it but if you've used it successfully please answer also.

Answer (score 4):

You can deploy the driver executable through SCCM the same way you deploy any other application through it.

Comment: I'd rather not go the driver executable route because of all the bloatware that is sometimes contained within. Ideally it would just add the inf files to the machine and do a look at each piece of hardware and update the driver for it if a better one now exists on the machine. Too busy to write it myself....